# Gimp fill exact selection

Tags: gimp

I want to fill a selection in gimp with one color and only that color. No color mixing between neighbor pixels. How can I do that?

When I fill a selection, gimp does it like in the image below on the left side. I want a result shown on the right side.

[image: Left: selection with fill and blur at selection borders, Right: selection with pixelwise fill]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch the antialiasing off from the selection tool - It's in tool options.

[image]

No antialiasing creates other problems. You will need much higher resolution for the same apparent smoothness. Antialiasing is developed to prevent jaggy edges between 2 diffrent colors.

Answer (score 1):

If the selection is partial on some pixels, use `Select>Sharpen` (which is the same as thresholding the selection channel on the 50% mark).